# How to return the response of Node.js mysql query connection

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new at Node.js and I want to find something from database by using select query.
Here is my code.

```
var address = socket.request.client._peername.address;
    var ip_addrss = address.split("::ffff:");
    let mine = ip_addrss[1];

    var location = iplocation_find(mine);


    connection.connect( function () {
        // insert user data with IP, location --- has got a status.
        let stranger = "";
        var values = [];
        if (mine == null){
            mine = "local server";
        }
        values.push(mine);
        values.push('location');
        var sql = "INSERT INTO user_list (IP_address, location) VALUES (?)";
        connection.query(sql, [values], function (err, res){
            if (err) throw err;
        });

        // control chatting connection between users
        connection.query("SELECT IP_address FROM user_list WHERE status = ? AND location = ?", [0, "location"], function (err, res){
            if (err) throw err;
            stranger = res[0].IP_address;
            console.log(stranger);
        });
        var room_users = [];
        room_users.push(mine);
        room_users.push(stranger);
        console.log(room_users);
        connection.query("INSERT INTO chatting_status (IP_client_1, IP_client_2) VALUES (?)", [room_users], function (err, res){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('inserted');
        });
    });
```

Now the problem is "stranger". It is not working anymore. Just always null.
Please tell me how I can return value in mysql query statement.

on my console, shows this.

```
[ 'local server', '' ]
127.0.0.1
inserted
[ '192.168.1.100', '' ]
127.0.0.1
inserted
```

Above, 'local server' and '192.168.1.100' are values of mine. And also '127.0.0.1' is the value of stranger only in query. But out of query it is just null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using asynchronous operations with your `.connect()` and `.query()` calls.  To sequence code with asynchronous callbacks like this, you have to continue the flow of control inside the callback and then communicate back errors or result via a callback.

You could do that like this:

```
let address = socket.request.client._peername.address;
let ip_addrss = address.split("::ffff:");
let mine = ip_addrss[1];

let location = iplocation_find(mine);

function run(callback) {

    connection.connect( function () {
        // insert user data with IP, location --- has got a status.
        let values = [];
        if (mine == null){
            mine = "local server";
        }
        values.push(mine);
        values.push('location');
        var sql = "INSERT INTO user_list (IP_address, location) VALUES (?)";
        connection.query(sql, [values], function (err, res){
            if (err) return callback(err);

            // control chatting connection between users
            connection.query("SELECT IP_address FROM user_list WHERE status = ? AND location = ?", [0, "location"], function (err, res){
                if (err) return callback(err);

                let stranger = res[0].IP_address;
                console.log(stranger);

                let room_users = [];
                room_users.push(mine);
                room_users.push(stranger);
                console.log(room_users);
                connection.query("INSERT INTO chatting_status (IP_client_1, IP_client_2) VALUES (?)", [room_users], function (err, res){
                    if (err) return callback(err);

                    console.log('inserted');
                    callback(null, {stranger: stranger, room_users: room_users});
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

run((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

---

Personally, this continually nesting callback code is a drawback of writing sequenced asynchronous code with plain callbacks.  I would prefer to use the promise interface to your database and write promise-based code using `async/await` which will allow you to write more linear looking code.